# How to add elements dynamically using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I am trying to create a simple form builder using react + redux.

I am facing an issue with adding elements dynamically from the sidebar to the container.

action.js

```
export const addNewTextBox = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_NEW_TEXT_BOX'
    };
}

export const addNewName = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_NEW_NAME'
    };
}

export const updateChildren = (child) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_CHILDREN',
        child
    };
}
```

addElementsReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  addFormElementsVisible: false,
  textBoxNum: 0,
  nameNum: 0,
  childKey: 0,
  children: []
}

const addElements = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NEW_TEXT_BOX':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            textBoxNum: state.textBoxNum + 1,
            childKey: state.childKey + 1,
        });
    case 'ADD_NEW_NAME':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            nameNum: state.nameNum + 1,
            childKey: state.childKey + 1,
        });
    case 'UPDATE_CHILDREN':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            children: state.children.concat([action.child])
        });
    default:
        return state
    }
}

export default addElements;
```

The above reducer and action is being passed in my Layout.js file which renders the sidebar and the container for adding elements.

Layout.js

```
<Sidebar
textBoxNum={this.props.textBoxNum}
nameNum={this.props.nameNum}
childKey={this.props.childKey}
updateChildren={this.props.actions.updateChildren}
addNewTextBox={this.props.actions.addNewTextBox}
addNewName={this.props.actions.addNewName}/>

<Create children={this.props.children}/>
```

From create I am sending children to ElementsContainer.js

```
<div>
    <div className="new_elements">
        {(() => {
           this.props.children.map((child) => {
               return (
                  <JsxParser
                      components={[TextBox]}
                      jsx={child}
                  />
               );
            })
         })()}
      </div>
   </div>
```

`this.props.children` renders an array of elements from the sidebar.

How do I push the elements from my sidebar to the childrens array and render it on my container?

If this is a duplicate kindly guide me to the solution. If this is not enough, kindly let me know what more clarification can I provide on my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{() => {
  return( //add return
   this.props.children.map((child) => {
    return(
        //your code
      )
  })
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSX, the content between `<MyComponent>` and `</MyComponent>` are considered children and are passed as `children` props of that component... That is what may be happening to your `<Create />` component in your code sample... Change the `children` prop's name to something else, and see..

Comment: `<Create />` is the parent container which is passing down its props to the `<ElementContainer />` which renders the `{this.props.children}`

Comment: `<Create children={this.props.children}/>` will pass `null` as children, no matter what `this.props.children` is... because it is self-closing, ie. it doesn't have any children... I understood as you want to pass the `children` in your Redux state down to `ElementContainer`; then, pass it via something like this: `<Create myChildren={this.props.children} />` and amend the `Create` component internally to pass on that prop to `ElementContainer`.  Notice that `children` as props has a different meaning in JSX context, so I suggested to change it to something else, e.g. `myChildren`.

Comment: what do you mean by `amend the Create component internally to pass on that prop to ElementContainer`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the issue is one of these two things :

1. You're unable to pass `this.props.children` to `<Create/>` because of some weird JSX nomenclature that even @stafamus mentioned. Can you try doing `<Create passingMyChildren={this.props.myChildren}/>` instead? where you could store the array of `<Sidebar>` components in myChildren instead of `children`. Although frankly, I think this should be the issue that you are unable to receive nothing at `<Create/>` level. but again, let's give it a try. It could possibly be because of a reserved keyword for react. Like you can't give your prop a name 'this' because that'd be a reserved keyword. Similarly, let's try and see if this works. [Here.](https://learn.co/lessons/react-this-props-children)
2. I'm assuming you want multiple `<Sidebar>` elements to be inside your `this.props.children` array so `<Create>` can render it. This is my understanding of the problem. In JSX, if you have to create an array of View elements or div elements you can do something like this.

   `var rows = [];
   for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++){
   rows.push(<ObjectRow />);
   }
   return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;`

In your case, that should turn out to be :

```
var myChildren = [];
for(var i=0; i<numOfChildren; i++){
  myChildren.push(<Sidebar/>);
}
```

and then pass myChildren to `<Create/>`. I'm assuming you know how to write the `<Create/>` code. As in, be able to render a list kind of structure which could have multiple `ObjectRows`.

I hope I got the issue right.